# Xamarin.Forms WPF won't load VideoView

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, vlc, libvlc

I try to recreate the Xamarin.Forms [libvlcsharp Sample](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/tree/master/Samples/Forms) for myself.

On Android an iOS it works perfectly fine, but when i try to use the Xamarin.Forms WPF Implementation it won't even load the ContentPage any more.

As soon as i remove the VideoView from the ContentPage and replace it with an Label or something like that it works.

**In this case it works:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AwsomeSample"
         xmlns:shared="clr-namespace:LibVLCSharp.Forms.Shared;assembly=LibVLCSharp.Forms"
         x:Class="AwsomeSample.MainPage">
         <!--<shared:VideoView x:Name="videoView" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>-->
         <Label Text="Bool11"/>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

**And here not:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AwsomeSample"
         xmlns:shared="clr-namespace:LibVLCSharp.Forms.Shared;assembly=LibVLCSharp.Forms"
         x:Class="AwsomeSample.MainPage">
         <shared:VideoView x:Name="videoView" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
         <!--<Label Text="Bool11"/>-->
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

*Hope my english isn't that bad. ^^*

Comment: According to [Charles Roddie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4903561/charles-roddie), you may wait for https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/3482 (pull request created three months ago) to get merged into Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/issues/38, this has been fixed:

> Try with (at least) https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibVLCSharp.WPF/0.0.1-alpha2 and https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibVLCSharp.Forms.WPF/0.0.1-alpha1

I believe you can close this question now.